# How to use Perl CAM::PDF module to render a PDF

Tags: perl, parsing, pdf

I'm trying to search a remote PDF for a text string, and based on research, I installed the CAM::PDF module to my server using cPanel.

Here is my latest failed attempt using CAM::PDF as per [the documentation for the CAM::PDF::PageText module](http://search.cpan.org/~cdolan/CAM-PDF/lib/CAM/PDF/PageText.pm#FUNCTIONS).  In the code below, I'm just trying to `print` as a test to see if the PDF is properly rendered.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use cPanelUserConfig;

....

use CAM::PDF;

....

my $pdf = CAM::PDF->new("myfile.pdf");    
my $contents = $pdf->getPageContentTree(1);
print CAM::PDF::PageText->render($contents);
```

And this gives me the following error:

> Can't locate the object method "render" via package "CAM::PDF::PageText" at ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here at the top...

```
use CAM::PDF;
```

I assumed this will use the whole CAM::PDF package.

However, instead I needed...

```
use CAM::PDF;
use CAM::PDF::PageText;
```